# create an ember slug for seo while only using the model id

Tags: ember.js

I want to improve my url mainly for seo purposes. I'm creating a slug server side, and would like to show that in the url. My ideal url would be `/search/show/nice-part/90`. I want to use the 90 as the id, and that is enough for me to find models etc.
I know I can change the route to be `{path: 'show/:slug/:model_id}`, then add a `serialize` method AND change all the link-to's from only containing the id to containing the id and the slug. It's that last part that I don't want.

I only want to use the id's in the link-to, as that is enough for me to find and manipulate the model. Is there a way to get this done? Only use the slug to make the url more meaningful and at the same time continue using the id only?

My current show route is the default

```
/search/show/90
```

and the corresponding route looks like:

```
  this.resource('search', function(){
    this.route('index');
    this.route('show', { path: 'show/:holiday_id' } );
  });
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it cannot currently be done. Do you have multiple model IDs with the same slug?

Comment: I'm not sure if I would have duplicated slugs, but it doesn't feel safe to trust on the slug alone and remove the id all together. In theory I should not have duplicated slugs

Comment: Using the slug to query your model is a common pattern of web apps. Instead of using find('modelName', param.id) --> find('modelName', {slug: param.slug})